# I am getting error in my method. I have implemented the method but it still showing the error

Tags: android

**this is my Common.java. i using a list of question here.should i implement my getUserName() here? my only error is getCurrentUser().**

```
package sonu.enigma.Common;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import sonu.enigma.Model.Question;

/**
 * Created by PAWAN on 04-10-2017.
 */

public class Common {
    public static String CategoryId;
    public static String CurrentUser;
    public static List<Question>questionList=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

`My error is here in`getUserName()`. I have implemented the method in other class as`User.java` . but still its showing the error her. can anyone help me to fix it? should i write my User.java again? or is there any problem in my class? thanks in advance.

```
package sonu.enigma;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import sonu.enigma.Common.Common;
import sonu.enigma.Model.QuestionScore;

public class Done extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnTryAgain;
    TextView txtResultScore, getTxtResultQuestion;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference question_score;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_done);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        question_score=database.getReference("Question_Score");
        txtResultScore=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotalScore);
        getTxtResultQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotalQuestion);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.doneProgressBar);
        btnTryAgain=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTryAgain);

        btnTryAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(Done.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });

        Bundle extra= getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extra!=null){
            int score=extra.getInt("SCORE");
            int totalQuestion=extra.getInt("TOTAL");
            int correctAnswer=extra.getInt("CORRECT");

            txtResultScore.setText(String.format("SCORE : %d", score));
            getTxtResultQuestion.setText(String.format("PASSED : %d / %d",correctAnswer, totalQuestion ));
            progressBar.setMax(totalQuestion);
            progressBar.setProgress(correctAnswer);

            question_score.child(String.format("%s_%s", Common.CurrentUser.getUserName(), Common.CategoryId))
                    .setValue(new QuestionScore(String.format("%s_%s", Common.CurrentUser.getUserName(), Common.CategoryId),Common.CurrentUser.getUserName(),String.valueOf(score)));

        }





    }
}
`**

`package sonu.enigma.Model;

/**
 * Created by PAWAN on 01-10-2017.
 */

public class User {
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    public User(){

    }
    public User(String userName, String password, String email){
        this.userName=userName;
        this.password=password;
        this.email =email;


    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
`**above is my User.java . **
```

**getUserName method**

[image]

Comment: You are using the getUserName like Common.CurrentUser.getUserName() but right way is  user_object.getUserName();

Comment: so what should i write instead?

Comment: post your Common.java file code

Comment: package sonu.enigma.Common;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import sonu.enigma.Model.Question;

/**
 * Created by PAWAN on 04-10-2017.
 */

public class Common {
    public static String CategoryId;
    public static String CurrentUser;
    public static List<Question>questionList=new ArrayList<>();
}

Comment: public static String CurrentUser; <- this is String type, not your User class. Have you ever learnt OOP before?

Comment: #tan i m a beginner. i just asked little help sir

Comment: error: cannot find symbol method getUserName()..............i m getting this error

Comment: @sonu public static User CurrentUser = new User("Your Username","Your Password","abc@gmail.com"); try this

Comment: If also getting error, pressed Command + Enter (Mac)/ Alt + Enter (windows) in the red words, IDE will suggest you import class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because there is no method `getUserName()` in the class `String`. Instead of

```
public static String CurrentUser;
```

Use:

```
public static User CurrentUser;
```

OR

```
public static DataSnapshot CurrentUser;
```

Comment: Use `public static User CurrentUser;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
package sonu.enigma;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import sonu.enigma.Common.Common;
import sonu.enigma.Model.QuestionScore;

public class Done extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnTryAgain;
    TextView txtResultScore, getTxtResultQuestion;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference question_score;
    User user_oject;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_done);
        user_oject=new User();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        question_score=database.getReference("Question_Score");
        txtResultScore=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotalScore);
        getTxtResultQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotalQuestion);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.doneProgressBar);
        btnTryAgain=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTryAgain);

        btnTryAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(Done.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });

        Bundle extra= getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extra!=null){
            int score=extra.getInt("SCORE");
            int totalQuestion=extra.getInt("TOTAL");
            int correctAnswer=extra.getInt("CORRECT");

            txtResultScore.setText(String.format("SCORE : %d", score));
            getTxtResultQuestion.setText(String.format("PASSED : %d / %d",correctAnswer, totalQuestion ));
            progressBar.setMax(totalQuestion);
            progressBar.setProgress(correctAnswer);

            question_score.child(String.format("%s_%s", user_oject.getUserName(), Common.CategoryId))
                    .setValue(new QuestionScore(String.format("%s_%s", user_oject.getUserName(), Common.CategoryId),user_oject.getUserName(),String.valueOf(score)));

        }

    }
}
`**

`package sonu.enigma.Model;

/**
 * Created by PAWAN on 01-10-2017.
 */

public class User {
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    public User(){

    }
    public User(String userName, String password, String email){
        this.userName=userName;
        this.password=password;
        this.email =email;


    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: same issue getting ?

Comment: Error:(60, 90) error: cannot find symbol method getUserName() .... i am getting this error Sir. when i changed Common.categoryUser to user_object .it still showing the error

Comment: User user_oject=new User(); write this statement before you are using.

Comment: I think you are wrong import statement remove user import and import again

Comment: where should i write this?

Comment: import sonu.enigma.Model.User.*; write this statement top of the screen below the package statement